# certmgr Unhandled Exception:The authentication or decryption has failed

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I am trying to add a SSL cert so I can use `SmtpClient` in a mono application with SSL enabled.

I have already run successfully:

```
mozroots --import --ask-remove --machine
```

Now I understand I need to add my specfic cert as using `SmtpClient` still fails, so I tried:

```
certmgr -ssl -m smtps://mail.amnet.net.au:25
```

And that fails with the below (NOTE: port 25 is correct in this case). (Incidentally trying https://encrypted.google.com works).

> Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.8.0
>   Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
>   Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ReadRecordBuffer (Int32 contentType, System.IO.Stream record) [0x00000] in :0
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ReadRecordBuffer (Int32 contentType, System.IO.Stream record) [0x00000] in :0
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0

Comment: some SSL changes have been included recently in mono, I recommend you to try v3.4.0 or master branch

Comment: Have you ever managed to fix this ? I'm still getting this error fone ONE SITE specifically, using https requests

Comment: Was two years ago but I remember something but overriding a method does the checking and just returning true - was a well known fix for this issue - though have to take care what the security implications of doing that are! I would be surprised if this is not fixed though - are you not using the latest mono?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926676/mono-webrequest-fails-with-https, if it is just one site - that could be the problem - cert for that site has been compromised! what does it look like in Chrome?